# PECL memcached installation gets error

Tags: software-installation, php

I installed Zend Server 6 (debian).

Also installed several packages:

```
apt-get install gcc
apt-get install g++
apt-get install libncurses5-dev 
apt-get install zlib1g
apt-get install zlib1g-dev
apt-get install libmemcached-dev
```

After that I tried to install pecl memcached:

```
/usr/local/zend/bin/pecl install memcached
```

I got some errors while pecl memcached installing:

http://codepad.org/iWuKlgxb

What is the reason of these errors?

Answer (score 1):

Good answer here:
http://blusmurf.net/2012/08/27/pecl-memcache-build-error/

```
# wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcached-2.1.0.tgz
#  /usr/local/zend/bin/phpize /root/memcached-2.1.0
```

Now we should change path in php_libmemcached_compat.h file:
`#include <libmemcached1.0/memcached.h>` to `#include </usr/include/libmemcached/memcached.h>`

```
# ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/zend/bin/php-config
# make
# make install
```

memcached.so installed but for some reason service memcached command coulnd't found.